# Making sense of limits at infinity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to define things like $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = + \infty$ for a function $f: E \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

In particular, when is it necessary that the point at which the limit point is taken is a limit point (it is necessary if this point is real, but what about the infinite case?).

What conditions must be imposed on the domain $E$? Does it need to be bounded in the infinite case.

Many thanks for any insights. I'm looking for a definition that is generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Limits involving $\pm \infty$ are best understood as being ordinary limits of functions  domain or codomain is a subset of *extended real numbers*, in which case the values $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ simply refer to ordinary points of said topological space and can be treated as any other.

In a typical basis for the topology on the extended real numbers, the neighborhoods of $+\infty$ are the intervals $(a, +\infty]$, and similarly for $-\infty$.

A subset of the reals, viewed as a subset of the extended reals, has $+\infty$ as a limit point if and only if it is unbounded in the positive direction.

The extended real numbers are even metrizable if you really want to use metric space methods rather than general topological ones. Of course, to do so you can't pick a metric extending the usual $d(a,b) = |a-b|$ metric.

Answer (score 1):

One quite flexible generalization of limits is to work with [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)).

If $f:E\to C$ where $E$ and $C$ are arbitrary sets, and $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are filters on $E$ and $C$, respectively, we can define

> Say that $f(x)\to \mathcal G$ as $x\to \mathcal F$ (here $\to$ is pronounced "**goes to**") if one of the following equivalent conditions hold:
>
> - For every $G\in\mathcal G$ there is an $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $f(F)\subseteq G$.
> - For every $G\in\mathcal G$, it holds that $f^{-1}(G)\in\mathcal F$.

If $E$ and $C$ are topological spaces and we choose $\mathcal F$ as a *punctured neighborhood filter* and $\mathcal G$ as a *neighborhood filter*, then this produces the usual notion of limit.

Different choices of $\mathcal F$ can encode different limits -- such as a left neighborhood filter for "$x$ approaches $x_0$ *from above*", or the filter of all supersets of $[n,\infty)$ for some $n$ to give "$x\to+\infty$".

Similarly, choices of $\mathcal G$ can vary what we claims happens to $f(x)$, such as -- again -- the filter of all supersets of $[n,\infty)$ to say $f(x)\to+\infty$, or the filter of all complements of bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$ for $f(x)\to\pm\infty$. Or even things we don't usually see in calculus, e.g. a one-sided neighborhood filter for "approaches $y_0$ *from below*", or a punctured neighborhood filter for "approaches but does not reach".

If $E$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ (that is, $f(x)$ is not defined for all real $x$), then we can construct an $\mathcal F$ by taking a filter on $\mathbb R$ and intersecting all of its elements with $E$. This expresses what happens for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ when $a$ is not in the domain of $f$: Take the neighborhood filter at $a$ in $\mathbb R$, and restrict it to the domain of $f$.

The condition that $a$ must be a limit point corresponds to demanding that $\varnothing\notin\mathcal F$, which is built into the definition of filter. Or in other words, the "intersect everything with $E$" construction will not produce a filter if the complement of $E$ is in the filter on $\mathbb R$ we start with.

The same construction can produce the filters for $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$ by intersecting with neighborhood filters on the extended real line (as Hurkyl explains).

This *also* produces $n\to\infty$ limits for *sequences* -- that is, functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

For $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$, the suitable requirement is that $E$ is not bounded above, i.e., for every $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $x \in E$ such that $x > \omega$.

(Since if $E$ is bounded above, then $f(x)$ is undefined for all sufficiently large $x$, and then it's meaningless to ask if $f(x)$ tends to something as $x \to +\infty$.)